# Generating Shapes with ShapeHelper in Orchard CMS - Type Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm building a site using Orchard CMS and creating my own custom modules. I have been following a couple of tutorials and so-far-so-good.

I don't understand how the .ShapeHelper() method works and it's giving me a little trouble.

The following code, from my Driver file, works perfectly fine and generates my view on the front-end.

```
protected override DriverResult Display(SubscribersFormPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {    
            // setup model
            part.DateStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
            return ContentShape("Parts_SubscribersForm", () => shapeHelper.DisplayTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/SubscribersForm", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
        }
```

However, I have seen on other tutorials that rather than `DisplayTemplate` the name of the part/view is used instead..which is what I would rather as especially when using the Shape Tracing module it's getting a little confusing seeing "DisplayTemplate" (as in the image below..) rather than a more recognisable name

[image]

I have tried simply changing my method to:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(SubscribersFormPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {    
            // setup model
            part.DateStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
            return ContentShape("Parts_SubscribersForm", () => shapeHelper.Parts_SubscribersForm(TemplateName: "Parts/SubscribersForm", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
        }
```

- notice the "Parts_SubscribersForm()" - though when I do this I get the following error...

[image]

I believe it is to do with where my views are located, though I also believe I have these in the correct folders that Orchard requires. This is my folder structure where my views are concerned...

[image]

Can anybody point me in the right direction - where I can use my parts name in the shapeHelper method, rather than "DisplayContent"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your display template directly inside `Views` folder (`/Views/Parts.SubscribersForm.cshtml`), not inside `DisplayTemplates`. Orchard, by convention, scans `Views` folders only when looking for shape templates. That `EditorTemplates` subfolder, on the other hand, holds templates for part editors, ie. those shapes returned from driver `Editor` methods.

What is that dynamic `shapeHelper` thing? In short - it's a *shape factory*. When you call eg. `shapeHelper.SomeShape(Foo: 1, Bar: "baz")`, it returns a shape object that corresponds to a `SomeShape.cshtml` template, with a dynamic model containing properties `Foo` and `Bar`. That template has to reside somewhere in `Views` folder of a module or theme. That's more or less all the magic.

If you want to understand shapes more - it's a good starting point: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes.